# Pointers for transitioning from SOAP to REST based services

Tags: rest, soap, transition

We currently have a SOAP based web service which is being used by various teams as the primary data source. We eventually want to transition to REST based services. We are reluctant to do this now as the clients would have to do changes.

What can we do to make this transition smooth?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: Is the back-end well separated from the soap interface? Do you need to make big structural changes to the back-end to add this new rest interface?

Comment: Back end is pretty much separated from the soap interface. No major changes needed there. It is the client side changes that worries us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't replace, add.

When you achieve feature parity, stop making updates to the SOAP API and declare it deprecated.